# How does one wrap numpy array types?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to make a class extending the numpy array base type,

```
class LemmaMatrix(numpy.ndarray):
    @classmethod
    def init_from_corpus(cls, ...): cls(numpy.empty(...))
```

But apparently, it will not allow multi-dimensional array types. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance!

```
ndarray(empty([3, 3]))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
class LemmaMatrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(subtype,data,dtype=None):
        subarr=np.empty(data,dtype=dtype)
        return subarr

lm=LemmaMatrix([3,3])
print(lm)
# [[  3.15913337e-260   4.94951870e+173   4.88364603e-309]
#  [  1.63321355e-301   4.80218258e-309   2.05227026e-287]
#  [  2.10277051e-309   2.07088188e+289   7.29366696e-304]]
```

You may also want read [this guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) for more information on how to subclass `ndarray`.

Comment: That looks great; the numpy.empty.view(LemmaMatrix) also seems good. Thanks! :)

Comment: One minor thing -- why not $size instead of $data? It is the dimensions, not the values, clearly?

Comment: @gatoatigrado: By all means, you could use something like `np.array(data).size`. I was guessing -- perhaps incorrectly -- what you wanted.